# How to use a channel, which is provided in a slashcommand received before in a onMessageReveived event?

Tags: java, discord, bots, discord-jda

I started coding a new project today and I'm having some issues. The bot should check every message in a channel provided in a slash command whether it's equal to a word, also provided in the slash command. For that I would normally need an onMessageReceived event, but I can't use something, which was provided in a slash command there. Has anyone an idea how to fix that?

I tried some things, but you can't make a public string in an onSlashCommandInteractionEvent. I don't know how I could fix that problem otherwise, because I would normally do something like

```
event.getOption("channel").getAsChannel().asTextChannel()
```

but you can only do that in the event. There you can't use it in another event though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the data on the channel somewhere, preferably in a separate file, but you can also make a public `List<TextChannel>` and work on that, only problem being it will be reset every time you restart the project.

Comment: Hi! Ty for your answer but how can I make a List public? It says "Modifier 'public' not allowed here" when I try `public List<TextChannel> channel = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: public keyword is only allowed in the class, you can't put it in a method.
Put it right under your 
```public class myClass extends ListenerAdapter  {
    public List<TextChannel> channel= new ArrayList<>();
}```
Also, please google easy questions like this, instead of asking on Stack ;)